# How can I check the last character in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these line options:

- <40m:22s - ok
- <40m:22m; - not ok
- <40h:22s;<40m:22m - ok
- <40m:22m;<40m:22m; - not ok

I need to check for semicolons. If I have one entry, then it shouldn't be. If I have several entries in a row, then the last entry should not have a semicolon.

Now I have so far only succeeded:

```
([<>][1-9][0-9][hms]:[1-9][0-9][hms][;?]+)(?<!;)
```

I will be grateful for any help, hint

Comment: Are you also attempting to validate the structure of the string or do you just need to check that it does not end with a semicolon? You could use [`endsWith(‘;’);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) if you just want to check that there isn’t a semicolon at the end.

Comment: `^[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms](?:;[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms])*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/btcyky/1/)) or `^(?:[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms](?:;(?!$)|$))+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/btcyky/3/))

Comment: yes, i also check this string too

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  yes, that's what I want to achieve. Wow, this is very cool)).

Comment: `[^;]$` checks if the last character is not a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms](?:;(?!$)|$))+$
```

Or, a bit more verbose since it includes a repetition of the main pattern:

```js
^[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms](?:;[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms])*$
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/btcyky/3) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/btcyky/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms](?:;(?!$)|$))+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `[<>]` - a  `<` or `>` char
  - `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
  - `[0-9]?` - an optional digit (remove `?` if it must be obligatory)
  - [hms] `-`h`,` m`or`s`
  - `:` - a colon
  - `[1-9][0-9]?[hms]` - a non-zero digit, an optional digit and `h`/`m`/`s`
  - `(?:;(?!$)|$)` - a `;` not at the end of string or end of string
- `$` - end of string.

The `^[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms](?:;[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms])*$` pattern follows the `^<MAIN>(?:<SEP><MAIN>)*$` scheme, and this pattern can be easily built dynamically using `RegExp` constructor.

```js
const texts = ['<40m:22s', '<40m:22m;', '<40h:22s;<40m:22m', '<40m:22m;<40m:22m;'];
const rx = /^(?:[<>][1-9][0-9]?[hms]:[1-9][0-9]?[hms](?:;(?!$)|$))+$/;
for (let text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', rx.test(text));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern for a delimited list is

```
^ item (delimiter item)* $
```

To avoid self-repetition and make it all more or less readable, it would make sense to use variables, template strings and whitespace. This way your regexp looks like a grammar definition (what it actually is) and not as a soup of symbols.

```js
let term = `[1-9] [0-9] [hms]`
let item = `< ${term} : ${term}`
let list = `^ ${item} ( ; ${item} )* $`

let re = new RegExp(list.replace(/\s/g, ''))

console.log(re)

test = `
<40m:22s
<40m:22m;
<40h:22s;<40m:22m
<40m:22m;<40m:22m;
`

for (t of test.trim().split('\n'))
    console.log(t, re.test(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplify the problem to `a = [<>][1-9][0-9][hms]:[1-9][0-9][hms]`, so the accepted strings can be

```
a - ok
a;a - ok
a; - not ok
a;a; - not ok
```

so our regex must end with `a` which leads to `a$`
now we want to accept none or multiple `a` with `;` between each `a`, the regex for that is `(a;)*`

combining these 2 will resut in `const regex = /^(a;)*a$/;`

now if we replace `a` with `[<>][1-9][0-9][hms]:[1-9][0-9][hms]` the result will be `const regex = /^([<>][1-9][0-9][hms]:[1-9][0-9][hms];)*[<>][1-9][0-9][hms]:[1-9][0-9][hms]$/;`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tPBQpk/1)